# SAXParseException in android

Tags: xml, android

I am following the book "Professional Android Application Development" and trying to implement some examples. In chapter 5 page 151, the following code throws a `SAXParseException`. Does anyone know why?

```
Document dom = db.parse(in);
```

I tried other XML files, same exception was thrown.

---

Stack trace is like:

> 01-07 00:23:58.875: WARN/System.err(221): org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: expected: /meta read: head (position:END_TAG @1:87 in java.io.InputStreamReader@43d0c720) 
>   01-07 00:23:58.895: WARN/System.err(221):     at org.apache.harmony.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:151)
>   01-07 00:23:58.906: WARN/System.err(221):     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:157)
>   01-07 00:23:58.915: WARN/System.err(221):     at com.paad.earthquake.Earthquake.refreshEarthquakes(Earthquake.java:82)
>   01-07 00:23:58.925: WARN/System.err(221):     at com.paad.earthquake.Earthquake.onCreate(Earthquake.java:60)
>   01-07 00:23:58.936: WARN/System.err(221):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   01-07 00:23:58.936: WARN/System.err(221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2444)
>   01-07 00:23:58.946: WARN/System.err(221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2497)
>   01-07 00:23:58.955: WARN/System.err(221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
>   01-07 00:23:58.966: WARN/System.err(221):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1848)
>   01-07 00:23:58.976: WARN/System.err(221):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   01-07 00:23:58.987: WARN/System.err(221):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
>   01-07 00:23:58.996: WARN/System.err(221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4338)
>   01-07 00:23:58.996: WARN/System.err(221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   01-07 00:23:59.026: WARN/System.err(221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   01-07 00:23:59.040: WARN/System.err(221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
>   01-07 00:23:59.046: WARN/System.err(221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
>   01-07 00:23:59.056: WARN/System.err(221):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Try printing out the full exception stack trace for *SAXParseException* & post it here.

Answer (score 2):

The parse method throws a SAXParseException in case there were any problems in parsing the XML that would cause the rest of the code not be be able to run, since if the XML is invalid then probably you don't want your code to continue.

The parse method declares that it `throws SAXParseException` so you must explicitly catch that exception when calling that method, e.g.

```
try {
    Document dom = db.parse(in);
} catch (SAXParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```